# Back button doesn't work if question is too long

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

If I open a question and the question title is too long, then the back button doesn't work and the only way to use the app again is to restart it.

- App Version: 1.4.5
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Current version of the app is 1.6.2. Please update.